# How to check the field data type (only) using postman?

Tags: api, types, postman

I am using Postman for few of the API verifications in which I would like to verify data type (string/integer) of few fields from the responses. I do not want to check the field value.
Ex:If I get a response something similar as below, I would like to check that sign_in_count always returns integer data type. :

```
    {
  "data": {
    "id": 274,
    "age": null,
    "email_id": "ojuuw@mailinator.com",
    "email_verification_flag": true,
    "ext_account": null,
    "ext_authenticator": null,
    "ext_user_id": null,
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "forgot_password_sent": null,
    "gender": null,
    "last_sign_in_at": null,
    "last_sign_in_ip": null,
    "region": "IN",
    "registered_using": null,
    "remember_created_at": null,
    "reset_password_sent_at": null,
    "reset_password_token": null,
    "sign_in_count": 0  
  }
}
```

Any help, much appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `typeof` function which returns the type of unevaluated operand.

`var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["sign_in_count is number"] = typeof(body.data.sign_in_count) === "number";
tests["firstname is string"] = typeof(body.data.firstname) === "string";`

Comment: doesn't work for me.. both these guys pass:`        pm.expect(typeof(data.user.email)==="string")
        pm.expect(typeof(data.user.email)==="number")` how can that be? 

Comment: I used `pm.expect(parseInt(responseBody)).to.be.a('number');` to check, if the body is a number - without JSON

Answer (score 4):

Postman has it´s on syntax on how to check for certain datatypes. No need to use `typeof` anymore.

```
var data = pm.response.json();

pm.expect(data[0].id).to.be.a("number");
pm.expect(data[0].email_id).to.be.a("string");
pm.expect(data[0].email_verification_flag).to.be.true;
```

Below is a solid way to check if the `id` property exist and is being returned correctly:

```
pm.test("Id should exist, not be null, be a number and be above zero", function () {
    pm.expect(data[0]).to.have.property('id');
    pm.expect(data[0].id).not.eql(null);
    pm.expect(data[0].id).to.be.a("number");
    pm.expect(data[0].id).be.above(0);
});
```