# How to test the data-types of number and null in Chai and Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman, chai

I am trying to verify the data-type of a response in my API test using Postman. The returned value can be **integer, float, or null**. 
How can I do this with Chai and in one statement?

these are my simplified assertions in a Postman test using javascript and Chai.

```
    pm.expect(23).to.be.a('number'); // PASS
    pm.expect(2.3).to.be.a('number'); // PASS
    pm.expect(23).to.be.oneOf(['number', null]); // FAIL
    pm.expect(2.3).to.be.oneOf(['number', null]); // FAIL
```

I expect all of the assertions to pass. 
Thanks and I appreciate any comment.

Comment: i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973515/how-to-check-the-field-data-type-only-using-postman/42992446 not sure about the chai part though

Comment: I guess you can jsut expect `typeof(body.data.sign_in_count) === "number"` to be true oO

Comment: shouldnt it be  pm.expect(typeof(23)).to.be.oneOf(['number', null]); ? doesnt work for null though

Answer (score 1):

so i assume you wnated a specialized method but i dont think that exists so i tricked a bit. Instead of using one predefined statemnt i made the stament myself and evaluated it to true

the main problem here is that typeof(null) returns 'object' which I assume wouldnt suffice as comparison

```
let element=[23,null,12];
  for(let e of element){

  //one statement
  pm.expect(e==null||typeof(e)=='number').to.be.true


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As `null` is an `object` type in JavaScript, write the test case as

```
pm.expect(typeof 23).to.be.oneOf(['number', 'object']);
```

That's probably an easy way, and can be used in simple checks. However, I'd recommend you to use the second way, i.e. using The fastest JSON Schema Validator.

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
schema = {
    "properties": {
        "myNumber": {
            "type": ["number","null"]
        }
    }
};

pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {myNumber: 23})).to.be.true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.statify` method from chai:

```js
expect(1).to.satisfy(function(num) {
  return num == null || Number.isInteger(num);
});
```

[Source](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy)